# XML validation with supplied xsd files

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xsd

This is not a specific programming question, but rather a request to know the proper way to do something.

"The Something": My code executes user-supplied powershell scripts that emit XML as their stdout. This output is supposed to adhere to a schema that we publish and deliver as part of our software's setup routines. We support versions in the output, so the customer's XML will have something like this for a version 2 output at the root of their XML:

```
<my_report version="2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com/permanent/config-2.0.xsd config-2.0.xsd">
```

The customer output XML may not be valid XML (hence the need for validation before we consume it).

My goal is to obtain the version attribute's value and ensure that it matches up with the proper .xsd file name provided, and then use that .xsd file to validate the output XML.

Since the output XML may not be valid, I can't rely on something like XElement.Parse() to get the XML into a variable to operate on it. So, I feel my only recourse is to parse the first element (my_report) and use string operations to do the determination.

Note: The machines that the code operates on are not guaranteed to have internet access.

My base questions: Is this sane thinking? Am I off in the weeds to do something like this? If it is not sane thinking, what would be good alternative(s)?

Platform is Windows Server 2008 R2, C# 4.0 Console Application type.

Answer (score 0):

Typically for versioning Xml document you use namespaces. In this approach each version has its own namespace and its own Xsd. To validate an Xml document you would load all the Xsd documents to one schema set and validate the xml. It's far from ideal (adds a lot of complexity, even though the documents are only different versions they semantically are totally unrelated while usually newer versions built on top of previous versions etc.) but I think it's still the most common thing to do. If you are just retrofitting validation to an existing system that already uses xml documents without namespaces for versioning employing the above approach would mean a lot of changes in your app (not to mention changes by the customers who send xml files). To discover the version you could first use just XmlReader - you would move to the root element and check whether the name is what you expect and the version attribute (or just the version as your schemas should reject documents with unexpected root element). Then you would throw the XmlReader instance you created and create a new one for validation (and possibly loading the document). This should be cheap since you don't actually read the whole document to discover the version but just the root element,  and if the document is not a valid Xml document (e.g. does not have root node etc.) the XmlReader will detect that and throw.